# Sping-boot configuration-properties and service layer injection

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, configurationproperties

I'm new to spring dependency-injection and am reaching out to learn about best practices. I would like to know if its a good design philosophy to inject classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` into service layer classes (annotated with `@Service`). Im trying to map properties in my `application.yml` to a config-class as follows -

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
class ApplicationConfig(
  val kafka: someDeeplyNestedType = SomeDeeplyNestedObj()
 ) {
       // helper functions
   }
```

I'm then injecting above config class in service layer as follows -

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationConfig::class)
class RestService(val config: ApplicationConfig) {
   init {
      // Reference config object
     // Reference application.yml properties via config object.
   }
}
```

I'm curious to know if I can improve upon my current implementation - not sure if its agreeable to pass `configuration` classes to `service-layer` classes. I'm also curious to know if theres any better approach to wiring `ApplicationConfig` without needing to use `EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is agreeable, [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.using-annotated-types), and probably "unrivaled" (only bounded by: ["limitations"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation) (no [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) -> helper functions!?;)).

> To work with `@ConfigurationProperties` beans, you can inject them in the same way as any other bean, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```java
> @Service
> public class MyService {
>
>    private final SomeProperties properties;
>    ...
> ```

The only problems can arise from the "deeply", not "owning" the (config) structure ...and possibliy from "helper functions".

#### But

The `prefix = "application"` "sounds" suspicious!

###### Note:

[Most - almost All] (official) `spring*` boot properties, are already "typesafe", and have their object/class representation in [spring-boot-autoconfigure packages](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure).

Please study that ["typesafe chapter"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties), but also gazing at [PropertySource Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-property-source-abstraction).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you care to explain your comment with an example if possible. I'm kinda facing the same issue that you mention - structured `configProperties` class that wraps `app.yml` and one that also provides some helper functions. Im worried this could lead to tight coupling.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I'm just trying to parse and bind application specific properties (that are part of app.yml) by specifying `application` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard rule for this as in Spring Boot we can add @EnableConfigurationProperties at a class level with stereotype annotations.

As a part of good practices EnableConfigurationProperties or any configuration thing should be part of Configuration class of or main spring boot class so any developer can easily figure out those configuration instead of going any specific service class and then check.

In your case, yo can use @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation in conjunction with @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: In general is it a good practice to reference configuration classes in service layer ?